# What is $scope.$apply() equivalent in Angular 6?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-scope, angular6

We had `$scope.$apply()` in angularjs that perform proper scope life cycle of angularjs.

Is there any equivalent to this in Angular 6?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Inject within your constructor

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
```

and call

```
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can inject [***ChangeDetectorRef***](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and use it for manually running change detection. It has methods that run change detection or stop it for that component. You can explore methods of `ChangeDetectorRef` looking above link.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   ...
})
export class MyComponent {

   constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef ) {

   }

}
```